# Is there a way to change text size on a console screen, specifically XAMPP shell console?

Tags: shell, console, text, xampp

I simply just want to be able to display the text at a smaller size as it currently is too large and messes with the display of the output (at least on my laptop screen which isn't all too big, but isn't small either)

I'm specifically using XAMPP shell console. I've looked around on the control panel but can't seem to find any options so I figured I should ask on her to see if anyone might know anything.

Comment: So we can see the exact name of the shell console and do some research, please paste `pstree $$` onto you cmd-line and execute. Then paste the cmd and it's output into the body of your question using the `{}` tool from the Edit menu for `code/data/output/errMsg` formatting. Good luck.